# READ REPORT for global classes?

Tags: abap

I tried READ REPORT for global class but it's not working. **I need to read global class' source code into table.**
I found SEO_METHOD_* FM, but those only returned metadata about class, not its source code.

Is there any FM or method similar to READ REPORT but for global classes ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Program SEO_CLASS_OUTPUT, it displays the code of the class on the screen. Have a look at the source code and see what it is doing.

Answer (score 2):

All ABAP code is stored in the table `REPOSRC`, reports, function modules, class pools, etc., in "include programs". This table may only be read via the ABAP statement `READ REPORT`.

You need to know what are the names of these include programs for a class pool.

For a class pool named `ZCL_X`, the ABAP source code is stored in these include programs:

- ZCL_X=========================CS : this include contains the whole source code, but only if it has been changed via the source-based editor or via Eclipse ADT.
- ZCL_X=========================CP : main code, which lists all or most of next include programs
  ** NB: CP starts always at the 31st character, all characters between class name and 31st character are to be replaced with `=`. Example: if the class pool is named ZCL_XXXXX, the include is named `ZCL_XXXXX=====================CP`.
- ZCL_X=========================CU : public section
- ZCL_X=========================CI : private section
- ZCL_X=========================CO : protected section
- ZCL_X=========================CM+++ : methods
  ** `+++` is a 3-characters code corresponding to a method as defined in table `TMDIR`. The column METHODNAME contains the method name and METHODINDX contains an integer used to build `+++`, examples:
  ** 1 to 9 : 001 to 009
  ** 10 to 35 : 00A to 00Z
  ** 36 to 45 : 010 to 019
  ** 46 to 71 : 01A to 01Z
  ** 72 to 81 : 020 to 02Z
  ** etc.
- ZCL_X=========================CCDEF : local class definitions
- ZCL_X=========================CCMAC : macros
- ZCL_X=========================CCIMP : local class implementations
- ZCL_X=========================CCAU : local test classes
- and more ...

Answer (score 1):

Use `CL_RECA_RS_SERVICES`, method `GET_SOURCE` like this:

```
CALL METHOD cl_reca_rs_services=>get_source
  EXPORTING
    id_objtype = 'CLAS'
    id_objname = 'CL_SALV_BS_RUNTIME_INFO'
  IMPORTING
    et_source  = DATA(source)
  EXCEPTIONS
    not_found  = 1
    others     = 2
  .
```